# Specify wufoo redirect url in form field

Tags: wufoo

I want to create a single wufoo form, and embed the form inside my own web pages.

WuFoo has a way to define the redirect URL within their GUI, but I want to make the redirect dynamic based on the REFERER value of where the wufoo data was posted form.

This will allow me to dynamically redirect back to a specific web site based on where the form data was entered.

Does anyone know if there is a way to specify the redirect url in a hiddent form field?

I know that I can create separate forms to accomplish this, but I want all of the entered data to be received in one wufoo form.

There doesn't appear to be any way to access the HTTP_REFERER value in WuFoo's form rules, so I don't think trying to use rules will work.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is no way to specify the return url in a form field (according to wufoo tech support).

But you can include hidden fields and use wufoo's rules to return to a URL based on those hidden fields.

In the end, I added code to wordpress's index.php to deal with this.